# Pine script if operator

Tags: pine-script

Simply get the error: "Syntax error at input ':'" at the first line of the following code:

```
punti = Scop > 0 and Scop >= DevMax ? 13 :
   Scop > 0 and Scop >= ScopMedian ? 10 : 
   Scop > 0 and Scop >= DevMin ? 5 : 
   Scop > 0 ? 1.0 : 
   Scop < 0 and Scop >= DevMax ? -1.0 : 
   Scop < 0 and Scop >= ScopMedian ? -5.0 : 
   Scop < 0 and Scop >= DevMin ? -10.0 :   
   Scop < 0 and Scop < DevMin : -13.0 :   
   na
```

I tried with 3, 4 and 5 spaces as indentation but still get the error.

Comment: Your second to last line uses two `:` instead of one `?` and one `:`.

Comment: could you rewrite the code? I don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
punti = Scop > 0 and Scop >= DevMax ? 13 :
   Scop > 0 and Scop >= ScopMedian ? 10 : 
   Scop > 0 and Scop >= DevMin ? 5 : 
   Scop > 0 ? 1.0 : 
   Scop < 0 and Scop >= DevMax ? -1.0 : 
   Scop < 0 and Scop >= ScopMedian ? -5.0 : 
   Scop < 0 and Scop >= DevMin ? -10.0 :   
   Scop < 0 and Scop < DevMin ? -13.0 :   
   na
```

Comment: Thanks for the working code. Could you explain where the difference is?